# Google maps v3 is very slow with developer tools open in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-devtools

Within the last few months, I have noticed that when Developer Tools is open in Google Chrome, zooming in and out of a Google Map (Google Maps JavaScript API v3) is *very* slow. When Developer Tools is not open, Google Maps zooms perfectly.

Is there a setting I can turn off to make Google Maps zoom fast again?

I have tried not recording my Network" traffic, and I am not running a "Profile" or anything.

This problem is on any site with Google Maps v3 JavaScript API -- even the Google Maps Sample page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: does it happens in more than one site?

Comment: For me using too many workspaces extremely slowed down devtools because I forgot it watches them for changes all the time.

Comment: @FelipeP I added a clarification that it happened on any site, and included an example site. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just clicked the little gear cog in the top right of Developer Tools, and then pressed "Restore defaults and reload", and now zooming Google Maps is fast again.

I must have had some setting checked that slowed it down.

Comment: Same thing was happening to me (OS X 10.10; Chrome v38 *and* v40 Canary) — restoring defaults fixed it perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Un-checking "Async" Checkbox in Developer Console -> Sources -> Async (Locate at left most of the screen) solved the problem for me.